# How to access the ajax response of the datatable outside the datatable in django?

Tags: javascript, django, datatables

In my django app the datatable makes a ajax REST api request where the response is as follows:

```
{
    "data": ["some content here"],
    "time_data": [
        {
            "Last_updated": "Jan 07 2020 06: 09 CST",
            "Next_scheduled": "Jan 07 2020 07: 09 CST"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the django REST API view is as follows:

```
class clustersView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        results = {}
        clusters = get_collection('clusters')
        results['data'] = ClusterSerializer(clusters, many=True).data
        results['time_data'] = get_collection('time_data')
        return Response(results)
```

In the above response json the `data` key has been accessed as follows and used to populate the datatable and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    myTable = $('#table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "{% url 'Clusters' %}",
        },
        columns: [
            { 'data': 'Master' },
            { 'data': 'Workers' },
            { 'data': 'Build' },
            { 'data': 'Team' }]
    });
});
```

But the next key i.e, `time_data` needs to be used in a div which is outside the datatable.

How can i access the response contents in javascript? So that i can use `time_data` from the response.

Note: accessing the django response variable `results` , throws a error that the variable is not defined.

Comment: response.time_data will return you the array so response.time_data[0] would be the first object containing the two key/values. Assuming `response` is the object you're processing in javascript

Comment: But maybe it would be more clear if you showed us your javascript code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @dirkgroten i have updated the question with more information, please look into it.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica whichever question link you posted does not answer my question. Also i have provided more info in the question so as it make it unique.

Comment: Look at [this](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr#Examples) for an example on how to access data and use it in another DOM element. And more on it [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc). When used as callback you can manipulate the response before it is passed to DataTables, and obviously initialize or populate other elements as well :

```js
myTable = $('#table').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    type: "GET",
    url: "{% url 'Clusters' %}",
    dataSrc: function(data) {
      doSomethingWith( data.time_data )
      return data.data
    }
  },
  columns: [ ... ]
})
```